# CiviCRM install "Too many open files" error

Tags: joomla, error, installation

Is there a way to get the installer for Joomla to open fewer files at all at once?

Or is there another way to manually install CiviCRM without using the install process?

I've updated CiviCRM successfully many times in the past on Joomla, but now v5.45.1 is giving me trouble. The error I'm getting is always from the bower components part of the install process. Like these, from 4 different attempts:

```
/home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2_locale_tr.js

/home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jstree/LICENSE-MIT

/home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2_locale_hu.js

/home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/component.json
```

I asked the Server Admins to try the install, and they say the install process tries to open to many files. Max open files is 5060. Here are the "(Too many open files)" errors is the trace the Server Admins sent.

```
uNNN-XXXXXXXXXXX@sitegroundNNN.com:~$ grep -i "too many open files" /home/uNNN-XXXXXXXXXXX/strace-TID4164900-01-13-2022-23-51.txt
     0.000037 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/www/test310.xxxxxx.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge/config/replacements.php", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
     0.000054 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/.opcache/7.3.33-Nov 24 2021-07:30:33-71ccbac5de17e4d9f3e6b3ca328c15a3/home/customer/www/test310.xxxxxx.org/public_html/libraries/src/Log/Logger/MessagequeueLogger.php.bin", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
     0.000122 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/.opcache/7.3.33-Nov 24 2021-07:30:33-71ccbac5de17e4d9f3e6b3ca328c15a3/home/customer/www/test310.xxxxxx.org/public_html/libraries/src/Log/Logger/MessagequeueLogger.php.bin", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
     0.000035 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/.opcache/7.3.33-Nov 24 2021-07:30:33-71ccbac5de17e4d9f3e6b3ca328c15a3/home/customer/www/test310.xxxxxx.org/public_html/libraries/src/Log/Logger.php.bin", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
     0.000037 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/.opcache/7.3.33-Nov 24 2021-07:30:33-71ccbac5de17e4d9f3e6b3ca328c15a3/home/customer/www/test310.xxxxxx.org/public_html/libraries/src/Log/Logger.php.bin", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
uNNN-XXXXXXXXXXX@sitegroundNNN.com:~$
```

Environment details:

> **Joomla! Instance ::** Joomla! **3.10.4**-Stable (Daraja) 11-December-2021
> **Joomla! Platform ::**  Joomla Platform **13.1.0**-Stable (Curiosity) 24-Apr-2013
> **Joomla! Configured ::** Yes | Writable (644) | 
> **Configuration Options :: Offline:** false | **SEF:** true | **SEF Suffix:** true | **SEF ReWrite:** true | **.htaccess/web.config:** Yes | **GZip:** true | **Cache:** false | **CacheTime:** 15 | **CacheHandler:** file | **CachePlatformPrefix:** false | **FTP Layer:** false | **Proxy:** false | **LiveSite:**  | **Session lifetime:** 180 | **Session handler:** database | **Shared sessions:** false | **SSL:** 2 | **Error Reporting:** default | **Site Debug:** false | **Language Debug:** false | **Default Access:** 1 | **Unicode Slugs:** false | **dbConnection Type:** mysqli | **PHP Supports J! 3.10.4:** Yes | **Database Supports J! 3.10.4:** Yes | **Database Credentials Present:** Yes |
>
> **Host Configuration :: OS:** Linux |  **OS Version:** 3.12.18-clouder0 | **Technology:** x86_64 | **Web Server:** Apache | **Encoding:**  |  **System TMP Writable:** Yes |   **Free Disk Space :** 891.92 GiB |
>
> **PHP Configuration :: Version:** **7.4.27** | **PHP API:** **cgi-fcgi** | **Session Path Writable:** Yes | **Display Errors:** 0 | **Error Reporting:** 30709 | **Log Errors To:** php_errorlog | **Last Known Error:** 10th January 2022 17:06:04. | **Register Globals:**  | **Magic Quotes:**  | **Safe Mode:**  | **Allow url fopen:** 1 | **Open Base:**  | **Uploads:** 1 | **Max. Upload Size:** 256M | **Max. POST Size:** 256M | **Max. Input Time:** 120 | **Max. Execution Time:** 120 | **Memory Limit:** 768M
>
> **Database Configuration ::**  **Version:** **5.7.32-35-log** (Client:mysqlnd 7.4.27) | **Database Size:** 107.45 MiB | **#of Tables with config prefix:**  85 | **#of other Tables:**  165 | **User Privileges :** GRANT ALL

> **PHP Extensions ::** Core (7.4.27) | date (7.4.27) | **libxml** (7.4.27) | **openssl** (7.4.27) | pcre (7.4.27) | sqlite3 (7.4.27) | **zlib** (7.4.27) | bcmath (7.4.27) | bz2 (7.4.27) | calendar (7.4.27) | ctype (7.4.27) | **curl** (7.4.27) | dba (7.4.27) | dom (20031129) | enchant (7.4.27) | hash (7.4.27) | fileinfo (7.4.27) | filter (7.4.27) | ftp (7.4.27) | gd (7.4.27) | gettext (7.4.27) | gmp (7.4.27) | SPL (7.4.27) | **iconv** (7.4.27) | session (7.4.27) | intl (7.4.27) | json (7.4.27) | **mbstring** (7.4.27) | standard (7.4.27) | mysqlnd (mysqlnd 7.4.27) | pcntl (7.4.27) | **mysqli** (7.4.27) | PDO (7.4.27) | **pdo_mysql** (7.4.27) | pdo_pgsql (7.4.27) | pdo_sqlite (7.4.27) | pgsql (7.4.27) | Phar (7.4.27) | posix (7.4.27) | pspell (7.4.27) | readline (7.4.27) | Reflection (7.4.27) | imap (7.4.27) | shmop (7.4.27) | SimpleXML (7.4.27) | soap (7.4.27) | sockets (7.4.27) | sodium (7.4.27) | exif (7.4.27) | sysvmsg (7.4.27) | sysvsem (7.4.27) | tidy (7.4.27) | tokenizer (7.4.27) | **xml** (7.4.27) | xmlreader (7.4.27) | xmlrpc (7.4.27) | xmlwriter (7.4.27) | xsl (7.4.27) | **zip** (1.15.6) | **cgi-fcgi** (7.4.27) | memcached (3.1.0-dev) | Zend OPcache (7.4.27) | Zend Engine (3.4.0) |
> **Potential Missing Extensions ::**
>
> **Switch User Environment :: PHP CGI:** Yes | **Server SU:** Yes |  **PHP SU:** Yes |  **Potential Ownership Issues:** No

> **Core Folders ::** images/ (755) | components/ (755) | modules/ (755) | plugins/ (755) | language/ (755) | templates/ (755) | cache/ (755) | logs/ (755) | tmp/ (755) | administrator/components/ (755) | administrator/modules/ (755) | administrator/language/ (755) | administrator/templates/ (755) | administrator/logs/ (755) |

> **Components :: Site ::** 
>  **Core ::** com_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | com_mailto (3.0.0)  1 | 
> **3rd Party::** WF_LINK_SEARCH_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LINKS_JOOMLALINKS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_DAILYMOTION_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VINE_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_YOUTUBE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VIMEO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VIDEO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_AUDIO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FILESYSTEM_JOOMLA_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_POPUPS_JCEMEDIABOX_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_POPUPS_WINDOW_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_LISTS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_DIRECTIONALITY_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LINK_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_STYLESELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_REFERENCE_TITLE (2.9.11)  ? | WF_VISUALCHARS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FORMATSELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AUTOSAVE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_TEXTCASE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CHARMAP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_BROWSER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CLEANUP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SPELLCHECKER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ANCHOR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_PRINT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_HELP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SOURCE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | JCE - Noneditable (1.0.0)  ? | WF_FONTSIZESELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FULLSCREEN_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ARTICLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_EMOTIONS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FONTSELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_PREVIEW_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_NONBREAKING_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_WORDCOUNT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LAYER_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_VISUALBLOCKS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_HR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CONTEXTMENU_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ATTRIBUTES_TITLE (2.9.11)  ? | WF_CLIPBOARD_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_TABLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_STYLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_IMGMANAGER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SEARCHREPLACE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FONTCOLOR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_MEDIA_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_XHTMLXTRAS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_KITCHENSINK_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_INLINEPOPUPS_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? |
>
> **Components :: Admin ::** 
>  **Core ::** com_modules (3.0.0)  1 | com_installer (3.0.0)  1 | com_finder (3.0.0)  1 | com_checkin (3.0.0)  1 | com_admin (3.0.0)  1 | com_menus (3.0.0)  1 | com_postinstall (3.2.0)  1 | com_content (3.0.0)  1 | com_newsfeeds (3.0.0)  1 | com_login (3.0.0)  1 | com_templates (3.0.0)  1 | com_categories (3.0.0)  1 | com_cache (3.0.0)  1 | com_tags (3.1.0)  1 | com_joomlaupdate (3.10.1)  1 | com_contenthistory (3.2.0)  1 | com_cpanel (3.0.0)  1 | com_users (3.0.0)  1 | com_languages (3.0.0)  1 | com_messages (3.0.0)  1 | com_weblinks (3.9.0)  1 | com_plugins (3.0.0)  1 | com_redirect (3.0.0)  1 | com_fields (3.7.0)  1 | com_actionlogs (3.9.0)  1 | com_privacy (3.9.0)  1 | com_media (3.0.0)  1 | com_ajax (3.2.0)  1 | com_search (3.0.0)  1 | com_config (3.0.0)  1 | 
> **3rd Party::** Akeeba (8.0.11)  1 | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/scayt.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/replace.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/pastefromword.xml)  (0.2)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/link.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/image.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/autogrow.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/pastetext.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/wysiwygarea.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/flash.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/showblocks.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/contextmenu.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/removeformat.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/undo.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/editingblock.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/templates.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/indent.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/jabout.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/filebrowser.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/smiley.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/video.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/find.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/tab.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/toolbar.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/colordialog.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/enterkey.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/dialog.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/showborders.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/audio.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/font.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/colorbutton.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/format.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/imagedragndrop.xml)  (0.1)  ? | TreeLink (1.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/sourcearea.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Ark Editor Statistical Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Cpanel Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Pro Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Update Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Control Panel (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Vote Module (1.0.0)  ? | com_arkeditor (2.8.5)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | Search Kit (5.45.0)  ? | Contribution cancel actions (5.45.0)  ? | CKEditor4 (5.45.0)  ? | Theme: Greenwich (5.45.0)  ? | eway Single currency extension (5.45.0)  ? | Financial ACLs (5.45.0)  ? | Sequential credit notes (5.45.0)  ? | Message Administration (5.45.0)  ? | AuthX (5.45.0)  ? | OAuth Client (5.45.0)  ? | reCAPTCHA (5.45.0)  ? | FlexMailer (5.45.0)  ? | Event Cart (5.45.0)  ? | Form Core (5.45.0)  ? | Form Code Editor (5.45.0)  ? | Form Builder (5.45.0)  ? | Mock Form Collection (5.45.0)  ? | PayPal Payflow Pro Integration (5.45.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.7.4)  ? | Custom search framework (5.45.0)  ? | CiviCRM (5.41.1)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | Search Kit (5.45.0)  ? | Contribution cancel actions (5.45.0)  ? | Search Kit (1.0.beta3)  ? | CKEditor4 (5.45.0)  ? | Theme: Greenwich (5.45.0)  ? | eway Single currency extension (5.45.0)  ? | Financial ACLs (5.45.0)  ? | Sequential credit notes (5.45.0)  ? | Message Administration (5.45.0)  ? | API v4 (4.1.0)  ? | AuthX (5.45.0)  ? | OAuth Client (5.45.0)  ? | reCAPTCHA (5.45.0)  ? | FlexMailer (5.45.0)  ? | Event Cart (5.45.0)  ? | Form Core (5.45.0)  ? | Form Code Editor (5.45.0)  ? | Form Builder (5.45.0)  ? | Mock Form Collection (5.45.0)  ? | PayPal Payflow Pro Integration (5.45.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.7.4)  ? | Custom search framework (5.45.0)  ? | COM_JCE (2.9.14)  1 | CiviCRM (5.19.1)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | API v4 (4.3.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.6.2)  ? | COM_ARKMANAGER (2.0.1)  1 |
>
> **Modules :: Site ::** 
>  **Core ::** mod_syndicate (3.0.0)  1 | mod_whosonline (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_news (3.0.0)  1 | mod_related_items (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_archive (3.0.0)  1 | mod_tags_popular (3.1.0)  1 | mod_users_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_finder (3.0.0)  1 | mod_languages (3.5.0)  1 | mod_articles_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_breadcrumbs (3.0.0)  1 | mod_footer (3.0.0)  1 | mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_category (3.0.0)  1 | mod_random_image (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats (3.0.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_categories (3.0.0)  1 | mod_tags_similar (3.1.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_weblinks (3.9.0)  1 | mod_search (3.0.0)  1 | 
> **3rd Party::** Simple Spotlight (3.1)  1 | ARI Ext Menu (2.2.11)  1 | MOD_EASYFOLDERLISTING (2.9)  1 | Custom Inline HTML (1.0)  1 | TheGrue Menu (3.3)  1 | Simple File Upload v1.3 (for Joomla (1.3)  ? |
>
> **Modules :: Admin ::** 
>  **Core ::** mod_toolbar (3.0.0)  1 | mod_version (3.0.0)  1 | mod_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_logged (3.0.0)  1 | mod_title (3.0.0)  1 | mod_privacy_dashboard (3.9.0)  1 | mod_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_quickicon (3.0.0)  1 | mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats_admin (3.0.0)  1 | mod_submenu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_sampledata (3.8.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_status (3.0.0)  1 | mod_latestactions (3.9.0)  1 | 
> **3rd Party::** Ark Editor Statistical Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Cpanel Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Pro Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Update Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Control Panel (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Vote Module (1.0.0)  ? |
>
> **Libraries ::** 
>  **Core ::** 
> **3rd Party::** file_fof40 (4.1.1)  ? | file_fof30 (3.6.2)  ? |

> **Templates :: Site ::** protostar (1.0)  ? | rexford-XXXX (1.0.a)  1 | beez3 (3.1.0)  ? |
> **Templates :: Admin ::** **isis (1.0)**  1 | hathor (3.0.0)  1 |